# Domains of holomorphy and simply connected domains

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain of holomorphy, we can say  that $U$  is a simply connected domain?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: There are probably easier ways to do this, but it is a theorem of Gompf that if $S$ an open subset $\Bbb C^2$ is homeomorphic to a 2-handlebody then it is topologically isotopic to a Stein open set which implies it is a domain of holomorphy. In particular, $S^1 \times D^3$ is such an $S$ (it smoothly embeds in $\Bbb C^2$ and it has a handle decomposition with one 0-handle and one 1-handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by PVAL, the answer is no. Any domain in $\mathbb{C}$ is a domain of holomorphy, so in particular, for example $\mathbb{D}^*$, the punctured disk is one. (This particular domain is also easily seen directly to be a domain of holomorphy). Thus, one obtains a counterexample in $\mathbb{C}$, and taking the product with $B$, the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, one obtains the same in $\mathbb{C}^n$.